# Customise TableViewController of uitabbar overflow items in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbar

UIKit automatically manages the overflow items from the tabbar. When you select "More" the overflow items are displayed in a TableViewController. I am struggling to find documentation or previous answers detailing how to programatically customise this TableViewController (for example to fit the style of your application)? Mainly I am not sure how to access this TableViewController in order to then customise.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like the code below. Try to get the **topViewController**'s view of **moreNavigationController** as UITableView and set your custom UITableViewDelegate to it. In the delegate, you can override the WillDisplay cell function to customize the cell.

```
class ViewController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let moreListViewController = self.moreNavigationController.topViewController {
            if let moreListTableView = moreListViewController.view as? UITableView {
                moreListTableView.delegate = self
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.random
    }
}

private extension UIColor {
    static var random: UIColor {
        return .init(hue: .random(in: 0...1), saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```